# What is the utility of Query By Exemple in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I'm learning Hibernate , I found the query for exemple feature. However , I unsdertood it but the problem that I have is I can't see the utility of this featue of Hibernate . So my question is what is the benefits of this feature given by Hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

Queries By Example are best suited for implementing search forms where the user can filter the result using many fields of the Entity.

See for example this article: https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-query-example-qbe